# multiple custom cells-error in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier  = @"cellWithTextField";
        UserDetailCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellWithTextField"];
        cell.userDetailLabel.text  = [userDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
   else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        DetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellWithLabel"];
        cell.userInfoLabel.text  = [userInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"cell";
        static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"cellWithLabel";
        NewControllerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.detailLabel.text  = [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }

    }
```

this code shows error......control may reach non void function...what shoul i return...where ui am going wrong?

Comment: Try to declare those cellidentifiers into their relative section

Comment: the eroor is still there

Comment: If there r only three sections then avoid last else if part and change it to Only else. Replace else if to only else

Comment: Your code should like else { } into last part. You dont need if part into it

Comment: Just add `return nil` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define one more condition on else like this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier  = @"cellWithTextField";
    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"cellWithLabel";
    static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"cell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        UserDetailCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellWithTextField"];
        cell.userDetailLabel.text  = [userDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        DetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellWithLabel"];
        cell.userInfoLabel.text  = [userInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        NewControllerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.detailLabel.text  = [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    } else {
        // Some code to return default cell or return nil 
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: how can I add background colour to the seventh row of section 2?

Comment: if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 7 )

Answer (score 0):

Just return nil. 
if your code will work properly "return nil" will never be executed for section 0(zero) - 2.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `return nil` at the end of your function.
So your code will look like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier  = @"cellWithTextField";
  static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"cellWithLabel";
  static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"cell";

  if (indexPath.section == 0)   
  {
    UserDetailCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.userDetailLabel.text  = [userDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
 }  

 else if (indexPath.section == 1)   
 {
    DetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    cell.userInfoLabel.text  = [userInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
 }  

 else if (indexPath.section == 2)
 {
     NewControllerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
     cell.detailLabel.text  = [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     return cell;
 }

 // You can return here default cell or nil 
 return nil;

}
```